# Replace pandas column value based on condition and avoid "future warning"

Tags: pandas

`df['col_name'].loc[df['col_name'].isna()] = 'new_string'`

How can I perform this setting operation to avoid "FutureWarning: ChainedAssignmentError: behaviour will change in pandas 3.0!"?

Comment: `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].fillna('new_string')`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas-series-fillna),

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].fillna('new_string')
```

Using @TheHungryCub example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_name': [1, 2, None, 4, None, 6]})
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].fillna('new_string')
```

Output:

```
     col_name
0         1.0
1         2.0
2  new_string
3         4.0
4  new_string
5         6.0
```